# What's a good HTML template engine for C++?

Tags: c++, templates, template-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ HTML template framework, templatizing library, HTML generator library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355650/c-html-template-framework-templatizing-library-html-generator-library)

Planning to write a website in C++. Would like to use a template system like Clearsilver, but maybe there's a better alternative?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) (pronounced 'witty') is a C++ library and application server for developing and deploying web applications. It is not a 'framework', which enforces a way of programming, but a library.

Comment: That's sweet, I'm glad I asked then, even though it's a duplicate. :)

Comment: it is GPL license so my not be able to use in your commercial project.

Comment: this really completely answer a question "What's a good HTML template engine for C++"... while Wt has WTemplate class, it's kinda bad to have to link against whole Wt in order to use just that class.. plus it's WWidget, so there maybe some problems when used in other way than intended

Comment: An alternative could be Inja (https://github.com/pantor/inja) that's a template engine for modern C++, loosely inspired by jinja for python.

Answer (score 10):

To add to the previous question:

[CTemplate](http://code.google.com/p/google-ctemplate/)

[CTPP](http://ctpp.havoc.ru/en/)

You could also interface with ClearSilver (written in C) with C++.

Comment: CTemplate seems to be gone and CTPP seems to be also gone as it redirects to a russian website with some message (in russian)

Answer (score 10):

Check out [Grantlee](https://github.com/steveire/grantlee): based on Django's template system, but using C++ and Qt.

Comment: +1. I saw this lib presented at Qt Dev Days Berlin. Looked really neat. Will try it real soon in our apps.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Link: https://github.com/steveire/grantlee

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at [cgicc](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/) which help handling posted data, but it's not actually for the html generation part. Otherwise I think [Clearsilver](http://www.clearsilver.net/) is a very good template engine that has been used [professionally](http://www.clearsilver.net/examples.hdf)

EDIT: Old post, but looks like CS has been saved on github https://github.com/blong42/clearsilver

Comment: Dead link like many others here