# Out of the box HTML templates for Qt 5

Tags: c++, windows, qt, template-engine

I want to generate html files in qt 5 using some templates engine.
There is a www.grantlee.org but i can't compile it (getting  `Could NOT find QtCore.` error)

Is there any build library for qt 5 on windows that could do html templating?

EDIT: did someone compiled grantlee for qt 5?

Comment: please check these two links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355650/c-html-template-framework-templatizing-library-html-generator-library

and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537820/whats-a-good-html-template-engine-for-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Its not out of the box but i choose to use QCTemplate form http://code.google.com/p/qctemplate/</strike>

I made it with "qt-mustache" http://kdemonkey.blogspot.com/2012/08/qt-mustache-templating-library.html