# Text-template library in c++ for formatting mails, reports

Tags: c++, templates, text, formatting

I'm searching for simple way to have mail/report text templates, with variables, and loops of variable elements. For example:

Template is:

List of files is generated in __FOLDER__. It contains:\n

[__FILENAME__\t__FILESIZE__\n]

In the program there is replace of the variable __FOLDER__ with the run-time value of this folder; and the generated on run-time files are put in the report using loop over the template __FILENAME__\t__FILESIZE__\n.

Do you have an idea for library or framework in C++ to help me.
10x

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355650/c-html-template-framework-templatizing-library-html-generator-library (those don't have to be used with html)

Answer (score 1):

The often overlooked [m4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_%28computer_language%29) macro language (available on every Unix, and there seems to be a [windows version](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/m4.htm) too) is incredibly useful for this sort of thing.  Good docs [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html) and [here](http://mbreen.com/m4.html).