# C++ standard replacement for (s)printf

Tags: c++, string, string-formatting, iostream, stdio

I'm doing a server application in C++, and it provides an HTML page as response to HTTP requests.

The problem is that, currently, my webpage is written as a *constant string* in my code, and I insert other strings using `<<` operator and `std::stringstream`, still during the writing of the string itself. See the example to get it clearer:

```
std::string first("foo");
std::string second("bar");
std::string third("foobar");

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "<html>\n"
    "<head>\n"
    "<title>Bitches Brew</title>\n"
    "</head>\n"
    "<body>\n"
    "First string: "
    << first << "\n"
    "Second string: "
    << second << "\n"
    "Third string: "
    << third << "\n"
    "</body>\n"
    "</html>";
```

Happens though I cannot simply stuff the contents in a file, because the data mixed with the HTML structure will change during the execution. This means I can't simply write the entire page in a file, with the string values of `first`, `second`, and `third`, because these values will change dynamically.

For the first request I'd send the page with `first = "foo";`, whereas in the second request I'd have `first = "anything else"`.

Also, I could simply go back to `sscanf/sprintf` from `stdio.h` and insert the text I want -- I'd just have to replace the string gaps with the proper format (`%s`), read the HTML structure from a file, and insert whatever I wanted.

I'd like to do this in C++, without C library functions, but I couldn't figure out what to use to do this. What would be the C++ *standard* solution for this?

Comment: You're overwriting the `<html>\n` part.

Comment: @chris Thanks for pointing it out, but it does not really affect the problem here. I've edited the code, anyway.

Comment: @Rubens I'm not sure I understood the sentence "Happens though I cannot simply stuff the contents in a file, because the data mixed with the HTML structure will change during the execution." - could you please clarify? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AndyProwl Does the edit clarify that section?

Comment: @Rubens I think I start to understand, but I'm wondering why can't you just write to the file after the strings have taken their final values. Do you want to do something like write to a file and update the file automatically every time those strings change their value? If so, why would you want to do that? (I'm just curious, not questioning that you shouldn't want to do that)

Comment: did you have already tried to serialize ? otherwise you store the fixed part in an SQL database and read them and put everything togheter at runtime

Comment: I don't get what's your actual problem. Why do you need to store the HTML page in a file anyway? A typical server application would just send the content through the network.

Comment: @AndyProwl That's exactly what I want. And I'm doing it due to what I said in the very beginning: this is a simple server, that responds to some http requests sending a dynamically written webpage.

Comment: @Rubens If your purpose is to write a simple HTTP server then I think you do not need to store anything into a file, as a user pointed out in a previous comment, just send the content of the stream over the net

Comment: @AndyProwl This is what I'm doing, currently; I think my page is way too simple to use anything special to write it, but I wouldn't like to write the page structure itself by the way I'm doing it now. I'd like to have the very simple page structure in a file, and fill the *string gaps* with the content I want.

Comment: @Rubens OK, then you do not actually want to *write* a file, but rather *read* a template structure from a file, fill it in programmatically, and then send it as a response. Is that correct?

Comment: @AndyProwl Yes, that's exactly what I want, as well as pointed by "Bart van Ingen Schenau" too.

Comment: I'll stick to `(s)printf`; thank you all for the patience and attention!

Comment: @Rubens I think you should not stick to `printf`. I just posted an answer with sample program that should do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard C++ doesn't have a direct equivalent to `(s)printf`-like formatting other than `(s)printf` itself. However, there are plenty of formatting libraries that provide this functionality, like the [cppformat](https://github.com/cppformat/cppformat) library that includes a C++ implementation of Python's `str.format` and safe `printf`.

That said, I'd recommend using a template engine instead, see
[C++ HTML template framework, templatizing library, HTML generator library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355650/c-html-template-framework-templatizing-library-html-generator-library) .

Or you can always reinvent the wheel and write your own template engine by reading a file and replacing some placeholders with arguments.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf - Technically, standard C++ does include things like `sprintf`.  Still, using a template framework is a good suggestion.

Comment: @NateKohl But is it in `stdio.h` or in `iostream`?

Comment: It's in <stdio.h> (also <cstdio>), not <iostream>.  But it's still part of C++.

Comment: @NateKohl: You are right, I corrected the answer. What I really meant is that (s)printf is a C heritage, not a purely C++ thing and it has some limitations.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
void RenderWebPage(std::stringstream& ss, std::string& first, std::string& second, std::string& third)
{
    ss << "<html>\n"
        "<head>\n"
        "<title>Bitches Brew</title>\n"
        "</head>\n"
        "<body>\n"
        "First string: "
        << first << "\n"
        "Second string: "
        << second << "\n"
        "Third string: "
        << third << "\n"
        "</body>\n"
        "</html>";
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::string first("foo");
std::string second("bar");
std::string third("foobar");

RenderWebPage(ss, first, second, third);

first = "anything else";
RenderWebPage(ss, first, second, third);

second = "seconds too";
RenderWebPage(ss, first, second, third);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to read an HTML template from a file and then substitute the arguments.

Comment: This is what I'm doing, currently; I'd like to get rid of this *html coding* in C++, pretty much using *place holders*, but I wanted to have this facility from some standard C++ method -- like C's standard `(s)printf`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the desired result like this:

1. Store your static HTML in a file, with placeholders for the dynamic text
2. Read the HTML file into a `std::string`
3. For each piece of dynamic text, locate its placeholder in the string (`std::string::find`) and replace the placeholder with the dynamic text (`std::string::replace`).
4. Write the modified string to the final destination.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been planning to do; I simply would like to know if I could have the simplicity of `%s` replacement with `(s)printf`, but, as @vitaut said, there seems to be no *direct equivalent* for it.

Comment: @Rubens: You can still use printf if you want.

Comment: @vitaut Yes, I know, as well as I could use `printf` for some of `std::cout`'s job; I was just wondering if there was anything more C++ *standardized* to accomplish this. Seems I'll have to stick to `sprintf`, anyway \=

Comment: @Rubens: You could look into Boost.Format for a C++ equivalent of `printf`'s behaviour. Be aware that using format strings from external sources can be a security risk.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: Boost Format is extremely slow, I'd recommend https://github.com/c42f/tinyformat instead. It also provides printf's functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a framework as other answers (correctly) suggest, I guess you can take inspiration from this little program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

string instantiate_html(string const& templateHTML, map<string, string> const& replacements)
{
    string outputHTML = templateHTML;
    for (auto& entry : replacements)
    {
        string placeholder = "<$" + entry.first + "$>";
        size_t it = outputHTML.find(placeholder);
        if (it != string::npos)
        {
            outputHTML.replace(it, placeholder.size(), entry.second);
        }
    }

    return outputHTML;
}

int main()
{
    map<string, string> replacements;
    replacements["name"] = "Mark";
    replacements["surname"] = "Brown";

    // Normally you would read this string from your template file
    string templateHTML = "<html><body><$name$><$surname$></body></html>";

    string outputHTML = instantiate_html(templateHTML, replacements);

    cout << outputHTML;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Andy, I'm really thankful for your promptness, but this is an implementation of "Bart van Ingen Schenau" suggested; my will was really to know if there was some precious function from C++ hidden maybe in `iostream` that would do quite the same of `(s)printf`. +1 for your patience and promptness. Sorry if I haven't been clear enough by the beginning.

Comment: no problem, we're all here to learn, and sometimes making the right question is harder than giving the right answer. cheers

Comment: BTW, Boost.Format might be something like what you're looking for. It is not as efficient as `printf`, but it does the same things and ensures type safety.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be checking it out!

Comment: @AndyProwl: "Not as efficient" is an understatement. In fact Boost Format is horribly slow.

Comment: @vitaut: Agree. I just did not want to be too drastic, after all it does the job, it is type safe, and for a simple program it shouldn't be a performance killer. Of course, if the goal is to create a heavy load, scalable HTTP server, then it will likely have a serious impact. But then again I believe it would be better to rely on some serious framework, as other users suggested.