# constants in html like #define in C/C++

Tags: html, constants

I have to change product name in html help pages (Microsoft help workshop). Product name appears at many places in different html files. 
Is there anyway I could define constant in html files, and replace product name with constant.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is not possible in HTML, but it *is* possible in XHTML.

Since XHTML is XML based, you can define new entities within the DOCTYPE declaration. So for example, to define a new entity called `title`, you can do this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"
 [
  <!ENTITY title "Demonstration of entities in XHTML">
 ]
>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>&title;</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>&title;</h1>
  <p>As you may have guessed, the title of this document is <q>&title;</q>.</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

And this passes the W3C validator too!

Sorry I can't make this into a snippet, because SO doesn't do XHTML. But you can copy this source and paste it into an .xhtml file, or, look at this file (on my own website): http://temp.strictquirks.nl/demo-entities.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

No, HTML is a [markup language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language), not a programming language. It does not know variables or constants when used on its own. It is a set of rules for static document. What you need is a **HTML Templating Engine** that replaced placeholders with variables or constants. These variables/constants need to be managed by some other programming language, though.

There are various engines that can do the job for you for pretty much every programming language. [Jinja for JavaScript](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) is a common choice. If you are looking for something related to C++ in particular [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355650/c-html-template-framework-templatizing-library-html-generator-library) lists many options.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in html to create variables although you use given way

Create  tag with class name as

```
<span class="abc"></span>
```

At every place, where you want to have that constant value

Then, just before closing body tag, add JavaScript as

```
<script>
document.getElementByClassName('abc').innerHTML='CONSTANT';
```

Comment: Well, that doesn't make much difference, but for the sake of good practices, i edited my answer to add it before closing body tag, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag